# Getting personal messages function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to develop a better function and curious what others would suggest I do to it so that its not so robust and still accomplish what I need.

A couple of things I need to account for is when I have a last 5 messages as well as getting just the regular number of messages.

```
/**
 * Gets all or last $x number of personal messages of the specified user
 *
 * @param integer $user_id   User ID of the user specified
 * @param integer $limit   Limit of how many messages to retrieve
 * @param integer $timezone   The timezone offset of the user's geo location
 * @param string  $box   Loading either the inbox or outbox of messages
 * @param string  $date_format   The format for which the date needs to be ouputted
 * @param array   $display  Tells what kind of messages to retrieve (important or specific datetime or datetime range)
 * @return object/NULL
 */
public function get_personal_messages($user_id, $limit = NULL, $timezone, $box, $date_format, $display = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('personal_messages.message_id');
    $this->db->select('personal_messages.subject');
    $this->db->select('personal_messages.datetime_sent');
    $this->db->select('personal_messages.attachments');
    $this->db->select('personal_messages.priority');
    $this->db->select('personal_messages.message_content');
    if ($box == 'inbox')
    {
        $this->db->select('personal_messages.to_read AS message_read');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->select('personal_messages.from_read AS message_read');
    }
    if ($box == 'inbox')
    {
        $this->db->select('personal_messages.is_inbox_favorite AS is_favorite');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->select('personal_messages.is_outbox_favorite AS is_favorite');
    }
    $this->db->select('CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) AS sender_name', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('users.email_address AS sender_email_address');
    $this->db->select('user_profiles.user_avatar AS sender_avatar');
    $this->db->from('personal_messages');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = personal_messages.from_user_id');
    $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'users.user_id = user_profiles.user_id');
    if ($display['type'] == 'today')
    {
        $this->db->where('datetime_sent >', $display['values']['start_time']);
        $this->db->where('datetime_sent <', $display['values']['end_time']);
    }
    elseif ($display['type'] == 'this_week')
    {

    }
    elseif ($display['type'] == 'last_week')
    {

    }
    if ($box == 'inbox')
    {
        $this->db->where('personal_messages.to_user_id', $user_id);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('personal_messages.from_user_id', $user_id);
    }
    if ($limit != NULL)
    {
        if (is_numeric($limit))
        {
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        }
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $personal_messages = array();
    $personal_messages['messages'] = $query->result();
    if (count($personal_messages['messages']) > 0)
    {
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($personal_messages['messages']); $x++)
        {
            $attachments = $personal_messages['messages'][$x]->attachments;
            if ($this->functions_model->null_check($attachments) === FALSE)
            {
                $attachments = json_decode($attachments, TRUE);
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($attachments); $i++)
                {
                    $file_name = $attachments[$i];
                    $attachments[$i] = array();
                    $attachments[$i]['file_name'] = $file_name;
                    if ($this->functions_model->is_file('assets/downloads/'.$file_name, FALSE) === TRUE)
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_file'] = TRUE; 
                        $file_size =  $this->functions_model->bytes_to_size(filesize('assets/downloads/'.$file_name));
                        $attachments[$i]['file_size'] = $file_size;   
                        $attachments[$i]['file_location'] = 'assets/downloads/'.$file_name;                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_file'] = FALSE;    
                    }
                }
                $personal_messages['messages'][$x]->attachments = $attachments;
            }
            $personal_messages['messages'][$x]->datetime_sent = $this->functions_model->actual_time('Y-m-d g:i:s', $timezone, strtotime($personal_messages['messages'][$x]->datetime_sent));
            $personal_messages['messages'][$x]->datetime_sent = date($date_format, strtotime($personal_messages['messages'][$x]->datetime_sent)); 
            $personal_messages['messages'][$x]->datetime_sent = $this->functions_model->time_since(strtotime($personal_messages['messages'][$x]->datetime_sent));
            $avatar = $this->functions_model->site_url().'assets/themes/'.$this->config->item('default_theme').'/images/avatars/avatar.jpg';
            if ($this->functions_model->null_check($personal_messages['messages'][$x]->sender_avatar) === FALSE)
            {
                if ($this->functions_model->is_file('assets/themes/supr/images/avatars/'.$personal_messages['messages'][$x]->sender_avatar, FALSE) === TRUE)
                {
                    $avatar = $this->functions_model->site_url().'assets/themes/'.$this->config->item('default_theme').'/images/avatars/'.$personal_messages['messages'][$x]->sender_avatar;
                }
            }
            $personal_messages['messages'][$x]->sender_avatar = $avatar; 
        }
        $personal_messages['total_unread_messages'] = $this->get_users_unread_messages($user_id);
    }
    return $personal_messages;
}
```

Comment: Any ideas for me?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of `if ($box == 'inbox')` statements. Why not bunch them together into one `if` statement?